# Not going into if statement when pressing a button

Tags: php, html

I have an issue. I need the code to get into an if statement when it presses a button but it is not doing so.

I tried using both get and post

```
<form method="get" action="index.php">
    <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
        <?php
        echo "<img 
src=\"images/{$row['image']}\" alt=\"\" width=\"200\">";
        ?>
        <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title"><?php echo " 
{$row['type']} in {$row['town']} - &euro;{$row['price']}" ?></h5>
            <p class="card-text"></p>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary"
               name="favourites" id="favourites">Add to Wishlist</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
<?php
if (isset($_GET['favourites'])) {
    echo "hi";
    $add_to_wishlist_query = "INSERT INTO 
tbl_favourite (userId, propertyId) VALUES ({$_SESSION['loggedin']}, 
propertyId)";
    mysqli_query($link,
        $add_to_wishlist_query);
    echo "<div class='alert alert- 
success'>Property added to wishlist!</div>";
}
?>
```

I need it that when it goes into the if statement it performs what is in the if

Comment: Can you format the code, making it easier for us to read?

Comment: Links are not part of forms. They will not submit it.

Comment: Also your SQL is totally incorrect. Use prepared statements.

Comment: In addition to the above, where do you get the value for `propertyId`  from?

Comment: @Dharman what link? If you are talking about the one in action I also tried doing action="action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>""

Comment: An HTML anchor tag `<a ...>` is a link. You probably want a submit button instead.

Answer (score 0):

You have used HTML anchor tag (link) in the context of a form. Anchor tags are not form elements. If you click such link it will not submit the form. The purpose of link is to redirect your browser to another website (URL) when you click it. If you wanted to submit a form with some input fields, which I do not see at all in your code, then you would need to use a [`button`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button) or [`input[type=submit]`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/submit). When you click a button which is inside of a form, the browser will submit the whole form with all of the inputs inside.

If however, you wanted to just have a link to some other part of the website (which is unlikely looking at your PHP code), you can use `href` attribute value with query string.

```
<a href="?favourites=1" class="btn btn-primary" id="favourites">Add to Wishlist</a>
```

See the addition of `?favourites=1`? This will be interpreted by PHP to be:

```
$_GET['favourites'] = 1;
```

The `#` would perform no action on your page when you click the link, unless there is some JavaScript event attached to it.

On unrelated note. The SQL looks completely wrong and you should never put PHP variables inside SQL strings. Use parameterized **prepared statements** instead of manually building your queries. They are provided by [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) or by [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php).